# Copying packages to robot

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New to ROS here and I've been developing a simple package on my workstation. However, I want to run this package from my robot.

I could manually just copy the appropriate source files and rebuild it on the robot but that seems a little long winded - especially having to do this multiple times when developing.

I feel like I am missing something. What is the 'standard' way of doing this with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198604/copying-packages-to-robot/) by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most software developers use version control software to store all of their source code, which makes it easy to keep the source code synchronized between multiple computers and multiple users.

If you have a particular version control software that you're familiar with, try to use that.

If you're new to software development and version control, I recommend learning about git (version control software) and https://github.com (free hosting for git repositories).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on 2014-12-01**:
I have used Git a bit before, but it just seems odd that I would have to push changes up just so I can get my files across to the robot? Unsure  if you've used the Player framework before, but it allows you to deploy code from your workstation by passing in the IP address of the robot when launching

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-01**:
I haven't used Player, but I do know that ROS doesn't provide any deployment capabilities.

You can set up your git remotes so that you can pull directly between local machines, without having to go to github.com; this is usually what I do when I don't have an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/) to synchronize the workspace between your robot and your workstation. It goes with one click (using unison-gtk). If the processor architecture of your robot is different you would need to recompile everything on the robot though.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-01**:
I feel like this is not as good as using a proper source control tool.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-12-01**:
One doesn't exclude the other, I personally use both, unison is much faster (Especially when both robot and workstation have the same architecture, no need to recompile) and you can test your code before committing it (because not everybody is fully proficient with vim or nano, editing code via ssh)